# How to retrieve max value with xsl:sort

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a xml file which contains multiple elements of type 'advert'. This last contains as a sub-element price.

I wanna extract the max price value using `xsl:sort` and `xsl:for-each` which browse all the items.

Comment: You can use the `max()` function. I don't see a need for using `xsl:sort` or `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Can you give me an example plz

Comment: Would be better if you could post the example you are working on. Or you can go through the numerous examples on this site [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963067/how-to-get-maximum-value-under-same-node-in-xslt).

Comment: thnx a lot !! that's what I was looking for :)

Comment: Please don't tag your questions as **both** XSLT 1.0 **and** 2.0.

Comment: Is there a big difference between them ?

Comment: any way it's done !!! thnx again

Comment: "*Is there a big difference between them ?*" Yes: one has the max() function, the other doesn't. -- If you want an answer to your question, you will need to post some code - see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358577/xslt-selecting-min-max-and-avg-attribute-values-need-data-from-different-l/28359107#28359107

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments for other members, max simply could be used as is without the need of xslt sort and xslt for-each.

To be able to use the xsl in xsl as is, here is a simple piece of code to try:

```
<xsl:variable name="the_max">
<xsl:for-each select="Node/Item/year">
<xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending"/>
<xsl:if test="position()=1"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$the_max"/>
```

using XSL values as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Node>
<Item><year>1985</year></Item>
<Item><year>1986</year></Item>
<Item><year>1987</year></Item>
<Item><year>1988</year></Item>
<Item><year>1989</year></Item>
<Item><year>1909</year></Item>
<Item><year>1991</year></Item>
<Item><year>1992</year></Item>
<Item><year>1993</year></Item>
<Item><year>1994</year></Item>
<Item><year>1995</year></Item>
<Item><year>1996</year></Item>
</Node>
```